# Understanding how netty works

Tags: asynchronous, netty

I'm trying to understand how netty works, and after reading some of the documentation I was to  see if I understood how things work at a high level.

Basically netty has an event cycle, so whenever you make a call it gets serialized and the request gets pushed down to the o/s level, and it uses epoll and waits for an event to send back to netty.

When the operation system generates an event that netty subscribed to, netty then has an event loop that gets triggered.

Now the interested part here is, the event that gets triggered has to be parsed, and the client code (or custom code) has to figure out who actually this event is for.

So for example, if this was for a chat application, when a message is sent, it is up to the client code to figure out to send this message via ajax to the correct user.

Is this, at a high level, a correct overview of how netty works?

BTW, when netty listens for events sent via epoll, is this event loop single threaded or does it work from a pool of threads?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds correct to me.

There are more than one event loop thread in Netty, but it does not mean a single Channel's event is handled by multiple event loop threads.  Netty picks one thread and assigns it to a Channel.  Once assigned, all events related with the Channel is handled by the picked thread.

It does not also necessarily mean that an event loop thread handles only one Channel.  An event loop thread can handle multiple Channels.